# How to import a huge file into PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, cakephp, import

I am in a new project and I have to work with an existing PostgreSQL database now. The application is built with CakePHP. The problem I am facing while importing is that the file size of the database is around 4.8 GBs and I am totally new to PostgreSQL.

I have worked on MySql and NoSqls but PostgreSQL is appearing to be a tricky part for me. 
I even tried to import the file via Console, but again failed. I am using PostgreSQL on Ubuntu (Core i3). Please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Nishant Shrivastava

Comment: What format is the file in? How were you trying to do the import and what was the error you got at the console? What is your database schema?

Comment: Is this a full database dump (schema + data) you want to restore or just data you want to insert? Does the file contain `INSERT` or `COPY` statements? What PostgreSQL version are you running on?

Comment: "*but again failed*" is not a valid PostgreSQL error message

Comment: Show the file layout and the table layout that you are trying to import into. Are you just importing 1 file into 1 table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are more possibilities

```
psql yourdb -f yourfile
psql yourdb < yourfile
cat yourfile | psql yourdb

psql yourdb
\i yourdb
```

Comment: i've got about 8GB of sql file, and all these commands returning me "out of memeory" message

Comment: please recheck your postgresql configuration - mainly `work_mem` and `maintenance_work_mem`. Next important are operation system virtual management configuration - for example `overcommit_ratio` on Linux. Maybe your Postgres got too few memory from your o.s.

Comment: checked these configs in my postgresql.conf, #work_mem = 1MB, #maintenance_work_mem = 16MB

Should i change them, if yes, to what?

Comment: you can increase it as first step.

Comment: changed: work_mem = 500MB, maintenance_work_mem = 1000MB
returning still the same error

Comment: do you have some special data - long strings, blobs, bytea, jsons?

Comment: don't know as i even couldn't view it

Comment: It hard to help - SQL script is text file, so you can look inside via some less usage memory tools like less, cat, ..