# postgres out of memory while restore using psql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to restore a PostgresDB DB backup (sql file) using psql and getting "out of memory" error. I have alreadt rebooted the box

While the restore is happening I can see that memory consumption on the box increases  by 4 GB every minute (free -h). I have restarted the box before attempting the restore again

the backup file is around 200 gigs and box has 64 gigs RAM. could this be a problem? DO I need to make any buffer changes?

Are there are changes I need to make in postgresql.conf file? Please advise. Are there any buffer changes required in postgresql.conf file

Comment: Hope this links will be helpful: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134887/open-execute-huge-sql-file/134928, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579425/how-to-import-a-huge-file-into-postgresql, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58493/mysql-failing-and-very-slow-on-importing-a-large-file?rq=1

Comment: Check settings like shared_buffers, work_mem, maintenance_work_mem and make sure you have not set them too high.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you're restoring that you're restoring to the correct database and not the 'postgres' maintenance db.